# Counting duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following information

```
Game_id | Team
47      | 1
47      | 1
23      | 2
31      | 1
41      | 2
47      | 8
```

I want to count the Per Team Number from all matches that have been played.

I want it to be this way:

```
Team 1 has made 3 goals
Team 2 has made 2 goals
Team 8 made 1 goal.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use COUNT() aggregate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`, like:

```
SELECT Team, COUNT(Team) FROM myTable GROUP BY Team
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you! I thought this was going to be hard to solve.